# pinterest inspired dashboard layout

Tags: javascript, css, django, api, twitter-bootstrap

Over the weekend we had a massive hackathon in Sweden, and my pitch to the organizers a few weeks ago was to create a pinterest inspired web app for instagram, since they don't have a big web presence.

I am using twitter bootstrap to easy create the layout and wondering how I can perfect that pinterest type layout?

Here is a sample of the loop I am running.

```
{% for obj in images %}
    <div class='span3'>
        <div class='thumbnail'>
            <img src="{{ obj.images.low_resolution.url }}" href="{% url dashboard_get_media obj.id %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/><br />
            <div class='social-items'>
                ...
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            <div class='comment'>
                ...
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            {% for comment in obj.comments %}
                ...
                <div class='clearfix'></div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

the address is http://instadashapp.com/

Comment: From what I understand, JQuery's Masonry plugin was used. You can also [Check out this page where the developer of Pinterest chimed in:](http://www.quora.com/Pinterest/What-technology-is-used-to-generate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Comment: If you are interested in a CSS only solution have a look here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Masonry javascript plugin](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) is specifically written to create a grid of content that fills in as much whitespace as possible, if you're not opposed to including another plugin for your needs.